# Sorting JSON object by value of bool in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to work with JSON object I got from an API and I'm trying to find a way how to sort it by bool value inside. I had a feeling that this will be already answered the question, but I can't find a way to do it my way.

Here is my response (It's my API so I can change data types and add values if needed)

```
[
    {
        "name":"Name 1",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 1",
        "bool": false
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 2",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 2",
        "bool": false
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 3",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 3",
        "bool": true
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 4",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 4",
        "bool": false
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 5",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 5",
        "bool": true
    }
]
```

I want to have objects with `bool: true` on top, and those with `bool: false` on bottom.
I couldn't find a way to do it myself. I appreciate any help.

Comment: The JSON you provided is not an array.

Comment: To clarify, do the numbers of each object need to stay the same? Or do they just denote the order currently and they don't matter to you?

Comment: @Arcteezy they haven't asserted that it's an array

Comment: @Sean Yeah. But sorting the order of values in an object doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Sean No they don't have to stay the same

Comment: @krystof18 Are you planning to change the structure into an array?

Comment: Well, I can change the data structure whatever I want so if I just replace the first and last curly brackets it will be an array right? @Arcteezy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort),

```
array.sort(function(a,b){return b.bool-a.bool});

console.log(array);
```

If you want the reverse order,

```
array.sort(function(a,b){return a.bool-b.bool});
```

Comment: @Andy Yeah. Why?

Answer (score 2):

First, deconstruct the API response in key-value with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the value by bool and then construct the sorted result with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const obj = {
    "0":{
        "name":"Name 1",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 1",
        "bool": false
    },
    "1":{
        "name":"Name 2",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 2",
        "bool": false
    },
    "2":{
        "name":"Name 3",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 3",
        "bool": true
    },
    "3":{
        "name":"Name 4",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 4",
        "bool": false
    },
    "4":{
        "name":"Name 5",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 5",
        "bool": true
    }
}

const sorted = Object.entries(obj).sort( ([a_k, a_v], [b_k, b_v]) => b_v.bool - a_v.bool).reduce((acc, curr, idx) => Object.assign(acc, {[idx]: curr[1]}), {});
console.log(sorted);
```

**UPDATED**

```js
const list = [
    {
        "name":"Name 1",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 1",
        "bool": false
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 2",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 2",
        "bool": false
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 3",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 3",
        "bool": true
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 4",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 4",
        "bool": false
    },
    {
        "name":"Name 5",
        "photoUrl":"Photo url 5",
        "bool": true
    }
];
list.sort((a,b) => b.bool - a.bool);
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is what you need:

```
[...].sort(a => a.bool ? -1 : 1)
```

-1 will put all your objects at the beginning of your array where 'bool' is true